# math of the game vampires vs zombies

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic

If you have played the game ,and you must found that this game is somehow like dynamic programming, but i am not so sure about that. maybe you get better idea.

If you haven't , that's ok, I abstract the core , see blow:

**Common condition**

an *vampire lady* cost 100 coin, and produce 1 *pumpkin* in 20 seconds.

a *pumpkin cutter* cost 150 coin for building, cost 100 coin for upgrading to level 2, cost 150 for upgrading to level 3. at level "x", pumpkin cutter can turn "x" *pumpkin* into "x" *jack o lantern* in 15 seconds.

a *bomb maker* cost 200 coin for building ,cost 150 coin for upgrading to level 2, cost 200 for upgrading to level 3. at level "x", bomb maker can turn "x" *jack o lantern* and "x" *dynamite* into "x" *bomb* in 15 seconds.

you can buy a *dynamite* at *the market* in 10 coin, you can buy no more than 10 dynamite at a time, and it will take 13 seconds to produce. when producing you can't give any other order

buy *vampire lady* , build or upgrade buildings dont cost time. and *the market* is always there.

*wagon* can sell productions. it takes 15 seconds to turn productions into coins. it can only carry 2 kind of productions at a time and each one of them can not more than 5

here is the price for selling

*vampire lady* 50 coin

*pumpkin* 10 coin

*jack o lantern* 40 coin

*bomb* 120 coin

**Questions:**

1.start with 1 vampire lady, 100 coin. what's the shortest time to get 2 pumpkin?

2.start with 2 vampire lady, 200 coin. what's the shortest time to get 300 coin, 5 pumpkin?

3.start with 2 vampire lady, 280 coin. what's the shortest time to get 320 coin, 4 pumpkin, 1 jack o lantern?

4.start with 2 vampire lady, 130 coin, pumpkin cutter at level 1. what's the shortest time to get 4 vampire lady, 10 pumpkin, 8 jack o lantern?

5.start with 3 vampire lady, 100 coin, pumpkin cutter at level 1.what's the shortest time to get 250 coin, 6 jack o lantern , 1 bomb?

6.start with 3 vampire lady, 150 coin, pumpkin cutter at level 2. what's the shortest time to get 300 coin, 10 jack o lantern , 2 bomb?

7.start with 0 vampire lady, 340 coin, pumpkin cutter at level 1, bomb maker at level 2. what's the shortest time to get 10 vampire lady?

**Note:**

if the coin or vampire lady is the object, then you have to get to the object number, for example, 300 coin is the object, then you must have 300 coin, if you sell production and make 400 coin in total, but you dont have 300 coin ,then the mission is not complete.

if pumpkin or jack o lantern or bomb is the object, then you dont have to get to the object number. you just need get them in total. for example, 3 pumpkin is the object, then you can produce one then sell it, and repeat for three time, then you get 3 pumpkin in total, the mission is complete.

**Some manual analyse**

1. 2 vampire lady, 2 pumpkins. 20 seconds
2. Buy 1 vampire lady, as soon as you have 5 pumpkins, sell the 3 vampire ladies (150) plus 5 pumpkins (50). 20+20+15 = 55 seconds
3. Sell a vampire lady , at 00:15 you have 330 coin(done). buy a vampire lady, build the pumpkin cutter. at 00:20 you get 1 pumpkin(3 left), start the pumpkin cutter, at 00:35 the second vampire lady produce 1 pumpkin(2 left) and pumpkin cutter produce 1 jack o lantern(done). at 00:40 the first vampire lady produce 1 pumpkin(1 left), at 00:55 the second vampire lady produce 1 pumpkin(done)

Seems like dynamic programming can give me the optimum step.I wonder how?

Comment: As you said, It's looks like a **shortest path** problem.

Comment: Yeah, that's a new idea.